# How to send text message to Azure Bot?

Tags: android, azure, azure-functions, botframework, speech

Totally new to Azure and the services it offers, I face many questions about the "Speech" service and the bots that can be created on the Microsoft platform. Currently developing an Android mobile application I'd like to realize the following behavior:

- The user records a voice file from the app (using [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder)), this part is ok
- Once the recording is finished, this file is sent to Azure function(via an HTTP POST).
- The file is translated into [Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/speech-to-text-from-file?tabs=linux%2Cbrowser%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-java)
- The text is [sent](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/media/voice-assistants/overview-directlinespeech.png) (step 7) to the bot which reacts accordingly by executing an HTTP request.

[Scheme of the process I explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s61tS.png)

First of all I wanted to know if this scenario is possible or if I have to use the [Speech SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-sdk?tabs=windows%2Cubuntu%2Cios-xcode%2Cmac-xcode%2Candroid-studio) on my Android application.

Moreover if this scenario is possible, how do I send the text to the chatbot? I've checked this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) but it doesn't seem very relevant to me.

NB: My bot has been completely created using "Bot Framework Composer" for the moment, no code has been written, I just wanted to know if my scenario is plausible and above all possible.

Comment: Hi Sibue, please refer to the solution I provided below. If it works, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1):

Go through your steps, and I think it can be implemented. If you want to send text to bot, you can refer to this [request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-1-1-send-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#send-a-message).

[image]

Before that, you may need to [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-1-1-start-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) a conversation and get the `conversationId`.

Comment: Hello !

Thanks for you answer but this HTTP Request use text & not voice ??

I was thinking about using SDK Speech to translate Speech to text directly into app & send the result to the bot.

This allows me to skip the azure function part.

What do you think about it ?